# postgresql count uniques

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a structure `pageviews` like:

```
| main_group  | subgroup     | page  | uid   |  viewcount  |
-------------------------------------------------------------
| foo         | targeted     |  A    | 111   | 3           |
------------------------------------------------------------
| foo         | targeted     |  B    | 111   | 2           |
------------------------------------------------------------
| foo         | targeted     |  A    | 222   | 1           |
------------------------------------------------------------
| foo         | targeted     |  A    | 333   | 4           |
------------------------------------------------------------
| foo         | targeted     |  B    | 333   | 3           |
------------------------------------------------------------
| foo         | external     |  A    | 444   | 1           |
------------------------------------------------------------
| foo         | external     |  A    | 555   | 1           |
------------------------------------------------------------
| foo         | external     |  B    | 555   | 1           |
------------------------------------------------------------
```

So uids represent users who viewed a certain page `viewcount` number of times. But I only want the *unique* user counts, while keeping the group, subgroup, page information. I want this result:

```
| main_group  | subgroup     | page  | unique_viewcount  |
------------------------------------------------------------
| foo         | targeted     |  A    | 3                 |
------------------------------------------------------------
| foo         | targeted     |  B    | 2                 |
------------------------------------------------------------
| foo         | external     |  A    | 2                 |
------------------------------------------------------------
| foo         | external     |  B    | 1                 |
------------------------------------------------------------
```

I can't figure out how to write the select statement. I've tried:

```
select count (distinct (page, uid)) as unique_viewcount, main_group, subgroup, page
from pageviews
group by (main_group, subgroup, page, uid);
```

but each unique_viewcount is `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want `count(distinct uid)`:

```
select main_group, subgroup, page, count(distinct uid) as unique_viewcount 
from pageviews
group by main_group, subgroup, page;
```

Comment: omg (FACEPALM). There's no way i wouldn't have tried that first... something else was probably wrong and i kept adding fields because of group by complaints. Thanks!!